# PDA (Permissible Dating Age) Algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, formula

The project is to create a simple Python program that will prompt the user for his or her age and then print out the lower and upper age limits for the user's date based on the Permissible Dating Age Algorithm.

The PDA Algorithm is: d = a/2 + 7, a is your age, and d is the lowest permissible age of your date where a is an integer.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import random
import sys
import time
def findACompanion():
     print "Welcome to the Permissible Dating Age Program!"
     sys.stdoutflush()
     time.sleep(3)
     a = float(raw_input("What is your age?"))
     if a <= 14:
          print "You are too young!"
     else: 
          d = a/2 + 7
          print "You can date someone"
          print d
          print "years old."
```

It seems to be running okay, yet nothings printing out and I'm confused as to what's going wrong with the print statements.

Comment: Take a programming class, I believe your problems are beyond what we can help with on a forum. And the reverse formula is algebra, not programming.

Comment: you have a formula and you have the age as a string. turn the age into an int and then plug it into your formula

Comment: My life as a parent of teenage girls would have been easier if I had  known that there is an algorithm for determining permissible dating age.

Comment: If they didn't cover this stuff in your first day of class, get your money back. @JohnColeman I've actually seen this rule before, see http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=half-your-age-plus-seven and read down for a laugh.

Comment: @MarkRansom There's no money to get back, this is just a class in highschool.  Unfortunately the teacher doesn't do much teaching himself and I'm left with videos that aren't very informative. :/

Comment: Thanks for editing in your code. Now this becomes a real question.

Comment: Sharing your code is half of what is needed .. you also need to explain your "confusion".  For example, what is the output and how does it differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

You weren't that far off the mark to be honest but your print statements were not faulty. Rather, they are contained within a function that you never call so they never actually run. There is also a small typo. This code will run:

```
import random #Not needed with current code
import sys
import time

def findACompanion():
     print "Welcome to the Permissible Dating Age Program!"
     sys.stdout.flush() #You missed a full-stop
     time.sleep(3)
     a = float(raw_input("What is your age?"))
     if a <= 14:
          print "You are too young!"
     else: 
          d = a/2 + 7
          print "You can date someone"
          print d
          print "years old."

#Something to call your function and start it off
start_program  = findACompanion()
```

Stick with the classes, it won't take long till it falls into place. Being thrown in at the deep-end is the best way :)

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a function `findACompanion`, but nothing is calling the function, so none of the statements within the function are being executed. You can call it yourself from the prompt:

```
>>> findACompanion()
```

There's a convention that is common in Python to detect if you are running a file as your main program and to make the call automatically, see [Top-level script environment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html). The convention calls for the function to be called `main` but you can call anything you'd like.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    findACompanion()
```